# Script-Tag with username Password?

Tags: html

Is there a mechanism to authenticate a script tag when loading a file?

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
<script src="/scripts/test.js" username="user" password="pw">
```

Comment: Hm... What you want to achieve?

Comment: What kind of authentication is that?

Comment: noone yet. I am still looking into what is possible

Comment: Well, what do you want to authenticate? For what purpose? What are you trying to protect or whom are you trying to identify?

Comment: It's just a "normal" authentification process and I was curious wether or not there is a built-in mechanism in the script-tag or not.

Comment: A "normal" authentication process in this context makes no sense, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your server setup, maybe it'll work using a URL like this:

```
http://username:password@www.yourhost.com/whatever/script.js
```

But, if you have this hardcoded in your HTML source the whole authentication thing is completely without any sense... you are aware of this?

Comment: And it's been deprecated for ***years***.